# uiscrollview--do I understand this correct?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

ok, I have spent hours and hours trying to figure this out. read countless other questions on here, which have helped me understand how UI scrollview works, but which have not helped me actually implement one into my app. I think I finally understand--but it just doesnt seem correct. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong (if I am) in the process below:

1. Have new, empty view controller.
2. add scrollview to view controller.
3. Put constraints on scrollview: Pin 0, 0, 0 and 0 to the view.
4. insert new UIview inside the scrollview. rename is contentView
5. put constraints on contentView: 0, 0, 0 and 0, all against the scrollview.

Now here is the tricky part: uiscrollview doesnt have a specific size--it only takes on the size of the container (contentView) that is inside it. So unless you give the contentView a certain height and width, then it says "scrollview has ambiguous scrollable height/width."

OK, so that makes sense. So I want the scrollable content height to be 900, so I set the height of the contentView to 900. But, I do not want horizontal scrolling. Users don't like it and it makes for an ugly user interface. But, the problem is that I have to set the contentView to a certain width, or else the width is 0 and no content shows up inside it.

So, I choose a certain width, for example 320. This works great for the iPhone 4S and 5/5S. And if the 4.7" and 5.5" iphone's didnt exist, this would be fine. But it gets a little awkward for the larger iphone's, because then the the content on the scrollview can't fully go across the screen, it abruptly ends and doesn't look presentable.

So, is there any way around this? I have been just using a tableview instead in the past, but now I need access to something that the uitablecell class can't do, and that's not an option. I tried setting the contentView to equal widths of the Superview, and that didnt work either, i still recieved the message "scrollview has ambiguous scrollable width." I just want the width of the contentView to be 320 for iphone4/5, and for it to be 400 for the 6/6 plus. Is this possible?

Comment: swift or objective-C?

Comment: sorry forgot to label, in swift

Answer (score 0):

Constrain the scroll view's content view to be the same width as the *root* view (i.e. the one that contains the scroll view). Absolutely do not hard-code widths.

EDIT: Finally! Here's a screenshot of the storyboard I just created. I can put the project code on GitHub if anyone wants it.
[image]

Comment: For the height, I *never* set it explicitly (either in code or with a constraint). Instead, you constrain all of the content view's subcomponents vertically to each other and, in the case of the top and bottom subcomponents, to the top and bottom of the content view, respectively, such that the system can calculate an exact height for the content view.

Comment: I tried the code that you previously posted (which apparently was deleted), and that did not work either. 

NRitH: I tried this, and it work in the sense that I place an element (a label for example) on the view, give it constraints to the contentView, and in the simulator it shows up properly. But, when I place it on the view, it disappears, so all of the elements on the screen have to be "blindly" placed there. I also get the message "contentView, expected width = 600, actual width = 0"

Comment: I'll whip up a storyboard.

Comment: @NRitH, I don't let the system make these calculations, I do it msyelf due to how customized my views are and need to be, but I get it, I do

Comment: no no, I konw what you are doing, it's just a differnet concept but on the same plane as what I'm explaning, but for different purposes

Comment: I'm not sure how customized views affect anything. I do incredibly complex layouts entirely in storyboards.

Comment: I mean this, if I'm scrolling to 900 points past the last view at the bottom of the screen, the need to add 900 points after the last view in the scrollview, this is what i mean, its not something that can be set up without setting the height explicity

Comment: @NRitH  and yes, there's times that i must do this given the design requested, no, not scrolling to an actual 900 points past the current scrollview but scroling past a certain scrollable point, yes, to fit for example, a keyboard pop that take up room  but where the scrollview won't budge due to it NOT scrolling up far enough to allow for the keyboard, so it's in these situaitons, where now in all situations, I set the numbers explicitly using resizin macros, it just makes it simpler for me to flex when i need to flex

Comment: and so it's like this V:|-[_aView]-300-|   and the 300 is to account for the keyboard, but not all superview have a height for the keyboard of 300, so I flex this size using a macro to account for different iphone sizes, otherwise, this would look awkward on a smaller sized iphone screen

Comment: You get the keyboard's frame in keyboard-related notifications which is different topic entirely. Please keep this about the original question which seems to be mainly about how to make content view as wide as scroll view.

Comment: I'm done here, your flaming is really tiresome, but just for the reference: [UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification) / [UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification)